# Write two (or more) numbers as sum of multiples of other numbers (one, two or more)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following problem:

Numbers 32, 35 and 57 can be written as sum of multiples of 7 and 9:

```
32 = (7*2) + (9*2)
35 = (7*5) + (9*0)
57 = (7*3) + (9*4)
```

Is there any method to find those numbers, 7 and 9? 
The main purpose is to maintain the number of operations as low as possible (summations and multiplications).

I will give a bad example to get more clear: the same numbers can be written as sum of multiples of 2 and 5 as follows:

```
32 = (2*1) + (5*6)
35 = (2*0) + (5*7)
57 = (2*1) + (5*11)
```

This is not a good solution because to express 57 we have to do a total of 12 multiplications instead of 7 multiplication from the first example.

To be more clear, in the first example, 7 is multiplied by 2, 5 and 3 for 32, 35 and 57 respectively, and 9 is multiplied by 2, 0 and 4 for 32, 35 and 57 respectively. To sum up, 7 is multiplied ”by 10” and 9 is multiplied ”by 6”, in contrast with the second example where if we sum up 2 is multiplied ”by 2” and 5 is multiplied ”by 24”.

So, for the first example we have less additions to do (total of 10 + 6 + 3) compared to the second example (2 + 24 + 3).

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Is there any method to find **those numbers**?" What exactly do you want? Please make it clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "These number should be as great as possible"? Is $(7,9)$ "bigger" than $(2,14)$? When do you say that $(x,y)$ is "bigger" than $(x',y')$?

Comment: A method to find numbers 7 and 9 in that particular example. Like finding ”greatest common divisor” I need to know that there is a method to find numbers whose sum of multiples equals those given numbers (in that example 32, 35 and 57).

Comment: @Pgatti: but you can not write 57 as sum of multiples of 2 and 14; are there any x and y for you can write 57 = x*2 + y*14 ?

Comment: @PaulBoț It was just an example to understand how you want to compare two couples. Anyway, is (7,9) "bigger" than (56,1)? How you compare couples in general?

Comment: @PaulBoț Sorry, now I got what are you maximization requirements.

Comment: @Pgatti: I edited the explanation; I hope it is a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

If $$ax+by=c$$ and $d|c$ with $d=(a,b)$, then the linear Diophantine equation" has solution.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html